# Why does my Milestone Droid erroneously report a drained battery once every few weeks?

Tags: battery, motorola-milestone

Every so often, my phone (Motorola Milestone, firmware 2.1-update1) decides that the battery is almost drained and that I have to turn the phone off.  This may happen just a few hours after charging it, and a subsequent restart confirms that yes, the battery does still have a charge, still at 70-80% capacity.

This tends to happen every few weeks, and it's been happening basically ever since I bought the phone a few months ago, so I'm pretty sure it's not a charge memory issue, especially when combined with the fact that the problem is intermittent and very infrequent.

Does anyone know why this might happen, and what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this exact same issue on my Motorol DROID v1 (same hardware I believe).  With Android 2.0, 2.1, and 2.1 update 1 my phone would sometimes report the battery completely drained just a few minutes after unplugging it.  I have not seen this issue again since the 2.2 update.  Before the update the way I would get the phone to display the proper charge level was to plug in the USB charger for just a moment.  As soon as the phone saw that it was charging the charge level immediately displayed correctly.

Comment: How did you *get* the 2.2 update?  It's not being offered OTA...

Comment: The Motorola DROID got the 2.2 update over a month ago from Verizon. I also use to see this behavior but have yet to see it on 2.2.

Comment: I believe the 2.2 image for Milestone is floating around the web somewhere, and you can flash without rooting your phone.  Or you can wait for the official OTA update from your carrier.  I'm on Verizon and received the OTA update a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Some custom recovery images have a command to clear the battery cache, this has fixed similar problems on different phones for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although not generally recommended for Li-ion batteries, I believe a full discharge and recharge cycle will also clear these statistics.

Comment: What statistics are you referring to?  (And if this is due to battery statistics, why does rebooting seem to fix it temporarily?)

Comment: I was refering to the battery cache that schwiz posted about.  Im not entirely sure why rebooting would fix it.  Are you running a custom rom?

Comment: No, no custom anything on this.  It's not rooted.